# Change the IP-adress of a url in Chrome using a regular expression or similar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I work in a environment where I have to change a ip-adress in the hosts-file a lot.

The situation:

MyDomain.com runs local for development and on a public ip adress. I would like to add a button to chrome who will switch between the ip's.

By example:

1. Click button to run route MyDomain.com from 192.168.0.1
2. Click button to run route MyDOmain.com from 89.12.11.10

Please note:
I can not view the website by just approaching the ip-adress. It needs a approach with the full domain www.MyDomain.com.

This looks like a very close solution but misses the route from the ip:

[Change the current URL in Chrome using a regular expression or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138750/change-the-current-url-in-chrome-using-a-regular-expression-or-similar/2160762#2160762)

Does someone know how I can accomplish this for Google Chrome? Is it even possible with javascript?

Comment: I don't really catch up your problem ? Why you didn't use the solution that you've mentionned by adding the IP instead of a normal URL ?

Comment: What about running the development site on a different port? You could use `www.mydomain.com:81` and just forward that traffic to `192.168.0.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do it using javascript Chrome API. If you are willing to take [NPAPI](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/npapi.html) route then maybe there is a way, but it won't be an easy one.

Comment: I am taking a look on it. Perhaps it can be useful. I think it it might be a idea to work with the proxy-settings.

Comment: It is very hard to accomplish. I do not think I can develop it easily this way.