# How to redirect user to new link on clicking in chrome via extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a chrome extension which redirects the user to modified link when user clicks the extension button.
I created manifest.json,icon file,popup.html and popup.js
But my code is not working.

I have read the answer to a similar question but still I'm not able to resolve the problem.
Link--> [How to modify current url location in chrome via extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891738/how-to-modify-current-url-location-in-chrome-via-extensions)

Pseducode of what I am trying to do:
1.get url of current tab(suppose www[dot]xyz.com)
2.Modify the url (abcxyz[dot]com) 
3.update the link and redirect to new link (go to abcxyz[dot]com)

This is what I've written so far....

```
// To get the url

chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    // Do something
    var targ=tabs[0].url;

});


var toBeOmitted="xyz";
    var toBeAddded="abc";
    var newTarg=targ.replace(toBeOmitted,toBeAddded);

//to update to new url
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, function (tab) {
      chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url:newTarg});
});
```

I am not able to debug it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem in declaring variables.
Final code will look like this-->

```
//Declaring variables
var targ,newTarg;

chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    // Do something
    targ=tabs[0].url;
//defining variables here
    var toBeOmitted="xyz";
    var toBeAddded="abc";
//define newTarg without var(to make it global) or just declare outside
//and define here
    newTarg=targ.replace(toBeOmitted,toBeAddded);   
    return newTarg;
});





  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.update({url:newTarg});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the function `chrome.tabs.query`

If it still not working, try to replace `tab.id` with `null`, that way you also don't need to use `chrome.tabs.query`

Example:

```
chrome.tabs.update(null, {url:newTarg});
```

Comment: It's not working(null part).
Actually I missed to add closing part here but i had written it in my code