# How can I open a sidebar link in the same tab?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions, web-extension

Is there a way to open a link in a WebExtension sidebar to the currently active tab? I don't want to automatically open the link in a new tab. I'm talking about regular links:

```html
<a href="https://www.example.com">Example</a>
```

Things I've tried:

- Adding any `target` value to the `a` element does not seem to have the desired effect for any value.
- Calling `window.location.replace` opens the link in the sidebar instead of the currently active tab.
- Getting the current tab by using `browser.tabs.query` and setting `tab.url` for the sole result does nothing (even though I have added the `tabs` permission to `manifest.json`).

At this point, I'm kind of thinking this might not be possible. Is this the case?

Comment: Use browser.tabs.update

Comment: @wOxxOm Somewhat surprisingly that actually works. Thanks! If you'd like, you could post this as an answer instead, so I could accept it.

Comment: There's an [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891738/how-to-modify-current-url-location-in-chrome-via-extensions) for `chrome`, but it's conceptually the same.