# chrome.tabs.update is not working consistently

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Using `chrome.tabs` API I want to redirect a newly opened tab to a select (static) URL.

```js
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(async tab => {
  // Set URL
  let updateProps = {
    url: "https://github.com"
  }

  // Update the tab (redirect to URL)
  tab = await chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, updateProps)
  
  console.log(tab.pendingUrl) // https://github.com
})
```

The problem is consistency.
Most of the times, the tab is correctly redirected, while in the other 1 out of 10 scenarios it is not redirected at all.

That being said after the `chrome.tabs.update` call, the tab `pendingUrl` is correct every time.

I have the `tabs` permission in the manifest (version 3).

Edit:
Also, there are no errors in the console.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. The code is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to do the same thing and having the exact same consistency issue.

I was able to fix it by wrapping my `chrome.tabs.update()` statement inside of a `chrome.tabs.query()` statement, as seen in this thread: [How to modify current url location in chrome via extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891738/how-to-modify-current-url-location-in-chrome-via-extensions)