# Change and open current tab URL to something else after clicking a button in chrome extension using Javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I need a help in changing the current tab URL to something else; let's say;  https://stackoverflow.com/ using my chrome extension;

my javascript code is :

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
var tab = tabs[0];
console.log(tab.url);
});
```

In this code tab.url returns the URL of current page.
i want to do something like this-

```
if(tab.url=="https://www.google.com/")
 {
     //redirect this page to  https://stackoverflow.com/
 }
else
 {
   //stay on the same page
 }
```

basically what i want to achieve from the extension is to redirect to stackoverflow when the current tab is google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
let newUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
if(tab.url=="https://www.google.com/")
    chrome.tabs.update(undefined, { url: newUrl });
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891738/how-to-modify-current-url-location-in-chrome-via-extensions)

Comment: you could also use
chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { url: newUrl });

Comment: yes thankyou ..it is working.. i was searching for this from around last 3 days