# Get rid of "Can read and change all your data on all y.com websites" in Chrome App Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions

I'm trying to get rid of this permission requested by my app since my app technically doesn't do that. What the app does: grab event id from active tab as a variable i.e., y.com/`$eventID`, and button (in popup.html) that the user presses and takes them to x.com/`$eventID` URL.

Here is my manifest.json file:

```
    "name": "Exit Ticket",
    "version":"0.0.4",
    "description": "Access your session exit tickets, right from your AV session tab.",
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ],
    "icons": {
        "128":"assets/synth.png",
         "48":"assets/synth.png",
         "16":"assets/synth.png"
      },
    "background":{
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts":[
       {"matches": ["https://*y.com/*"],
       "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }

    ],
    
    "action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "assets/synth.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Exit Ticket",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "manifest_version": 3
}
```

My hypothesis is that the culprit is the `{"matches": ["https://*y.com/*"],` bit on contentscript variable. This warning appears to be making hesitant when onboarding.

Comment: The content script indeed allows changing all data on the matching sites. Judging by your description you don't need a content script at all. Instead you can use chrome.tabs.query to read the active URL and chrome.tans.update to change it ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29148469)).

Comment: Was also trying to get rid of this warning. It was shown up under extension Details tab, when was in developer mode (loading extension from disk). After I published it onto Chrome Web Store, this warning went away, together with "Allow access to file URLs" and "Collect errors" warnings.